# Turn a tibble into a named vector in R

Tags: r, tibble

I'd like to turn a tibble in R (portion of it is shown below) into a named vector, where each unique `gs_name` maps to a list of `ensembl_gene`s corresponding to it. How can I do this?

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  gs_name                  ensembl_gene  
  <chr>                    <chr>         
1 ABBUD_LIF_SIGNALING_1_DN WBGene00002717
2 ABBUD_LIF_SIGNALING_1_DN WBGene00006518
3 ABBUD_LIF_SIGNALING_1_DN WBGene00000542
4 ABBUD_UP WBGene00000546
5 ABBUD_UP WBGene00013434
6 ABBUD_UP WBGene00001579
```

Comment: `split(df$ensembl_genes, df$gs_name)`

Comment: Please use ``dput()`` to share your data and don't use images. Images are not good for people who are visually impaired and use screen readers and the data cannot be copied and pasted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` to get a named list.

```
res <- split(df$ensembl_genes, df$gs_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

`deframe()` could also be useful here

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("gs_name,ensembl_gene  
ABBUD_LIF_SIGNALING_1_DN,WBGene00002717
ABBUD_LIF_SIGNALING_1_DN,WBGene00006518
ABBUD_LIF_SIGNALING_1_DN,WBGene00000542
ABBUD_UP,WBGene00000546
ABBUD_UP,WBGene00013434
ABBUD_UP,WBGene00001579")

deframe(df)
#> ABBUD_LIF_SIGNALING_1_DN ABBUD_LIF_SIGNALING_1_DN ABBUD_LIF_SIGNALING_1_DN 
#>         "WBGene00002717"         "WBGene00006518"         "WBGene00000542" 
#>                 ABBUD_UP                 ABBUD_UP                 ABBUD_UP 
#>         "WBGene00000546"         "WBGene00013434"         "WBGene00001579"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>